# Raspberry Pi 3: Running arm32 programs on an arm64 system

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, arm, raspberry-pi3, shellexecute

I run my program perfectly on my Raspberry Pi 3 when I run 32bit Raspibian. It is a `Linux 5.10.33-v7+ #1 armv7l` system. The programs were compiled on this system, in C++. If I copy the executables to another card with that system, it works.

However, these same executables do not run when I use `Debian 4.19.181-1 aarch64 Linux 4.19.0.16-arm64` (I copy the compiled file and paste it on the other system ).

When trying to run, it returns:

> -bash: ./Myprogram: No such file or directory.

If I try to run with `bash Myprogram`, it returns:

> Myprogram: cannot execute binary file

From what I've researched, this is an incompatible architectural error.

I've already tried changing permissions with `chmod`.

I think 32bit files should work on a 64bit system.

The "file" command returns:

> ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux),
> dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for
> GNU/Linux 3.2.0,
> BuildID[sha1]=ad484c860b63e0d8735c2b7aa5c69f2e49caaf29, with
> debug_info, not stripped

Thank you so much

---

I understand the problem is the architecture. But why can the same processor (same raspbery) run an armv7l OS and also an arm64 OS? How does compatibility work?

Why does raspberry run both arm64 OS and armv7l OS but not programs?

Comment: @ChristianPastro an option would be to install a 64bit OS on your Pi3, since the Pi3 processor is a 64bit. A 32bit OS doesn't have the instruction for 64bit programs.

Answer (score 0):

it's not just a 32 or 64 bit problem .
you are two differents architectures, for your program to work  you have no choice, you must recompile it for this architecture.

If you want to make portability you can use systems like "Make".